# Is @Scheduled annotated method will get called twice if it is running on two different machines?

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have a method called sendEmail.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */3 * ? * *")
public void sendEmail()
{

}
```

This method will send an email at every 3 minutes. If this service is running on two different machines, will this method get called twice or not?

Answer (score 0):

> This method will send an email at every 3 minutes. If this service is running on two different machines will this method get called twice or not?

Yes, this method will be invoked even if two JVMs within the same machine running this code. If you want non duplicates, you need to put it into a message queue and take out and process or a database level check to avoid duplicates.